# Removing white segment from a svg image

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am designing an Arabic font for which I have created the glyphs using MetaFont and processed the MetaFont sources with MetaPost. As a result, I got an svg image for each of the glyph. There is one problem that I am facing and that is there is a white segment in some of these glyphs that is unpleasant and I would like to remove that white segment.

For instance, please have a look at my [Arabic digit 9](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08sgbJvIcACWmEzaEJRUjBaMkU/view?usp=sharing), as you can see on the top part of this digits, there is a circular-like white segment that I like to remove. How can I remove this unpleasant white segment in illustrator?

Comment: Hi Vafa, and welcome to GD.SE. See the Help center for guidelines on how to ask questions. So that we can answer this question, and that it will be useful to others in the future, get a screen shot with transparency and post that. Your link will eventually go down, after which nobody reading this would know what your were asking about.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve... what white segment? Can you show us how it is supposed to look?

Comment: Can we close this question as incomplete? Seems OP abandoned it, the link to the image is broken, the only answer given is quite confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Vafa...do you mean this part? [image] Is this part of your background in the image or is this the color of your art board in Illustrator? Use Direct Selection tool (keyboard shortcut A, or the white mouse pointer in the toolbox). If you cannot click on it after selecting it might be that your art board color itself is white. If this is the color of your art board then you can change it by following the steps on this image... hope this helps...  [image]